# Multiple relationships to single table Entity Framework asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-fluent-api

I've just started using Entity Framework for my next project and I'm struggling with the following. I have the following `ApplicationUser` class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser 
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

I have two classes that inherent from this class:

```
public class TrainerUser : ApplicationUser  
{
    public virtual ICollection<ClientUser> Clients { get; set; }
}

public class ClientUser : ApplicationUser 
{
    public string TrainerId { get; set; }
    public TrainerUser Trainer { get; set; }
}
```

The company class looks like this:

```
public class Company 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TrainerUser> Trainers { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClientUser> Clients { get; set; }
}
```

What I can't figure out is how I can use the fluent API to not include 3 different companyId columns in the `ApplicationUsers` table.

Currently I have the following fluent API configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TrainerUser>().HasRequired(c => c.Company).WithMany(t => t.Trainers).HasForeignKey(c => c.CompanyId);
modelBuilder.Entity<ClientUser>().HasRequired(c => c.Company).WithMany(c => c.Clients).HasForeignKey(c => c.CompanyId);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you tried to move the navigator to company currently in application user to the other inheriting classes?

Comment: if the `ApplicationUser` is not an entity in your application then you could make the class abstract and I think it should fix the issue, I would try that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding these to your code.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TrainerUser>().ToTable("TrainerUser");
modelBuilder.Entity<ClientUser>().ToTable("ClientUser");
```

If I am getting you right. you are trying to create a structure representing [Table Per Hierarchy (TPT)](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt). Read more about it at the link.

Basically what happens is when entity framework encounters inheritance in the entities. Its Default attempt to create tables is by creating column of the set of all properties of all the derived entities from a class with a discriminator column.

What you are trying to create is a separate table for every class in the hierarchy.

Comment: Hello Parv, that is correct. I did your suggestion but also move the navigator to the inheriting classes like Paul said. Combining the to solution resolved my problem. Thank you!